# Facebook Graph API - post to users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a form which is redirecting to a php script to add fields to a mysql database. Once it has been added I want the app to ask permission to publish to the users stream and once authorised I want a message to be published to the users wall.

here is what ive got so far. the mysql bit is working but the post to wall is not.

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());


$mysql="INSERT INTO  `dhxmascomp`.`users` (`user_id` , `name` , `user_email`) VALUES (NULL, '{$_GET[name]}','{$_GET[name2]}')";


if(!mysql_query($mysql)) 
die(mysql_error());


mysql_close();

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $FB_AppID,
    'secret' => $FB_AppSecret,
    'cookie' => true,));


$user = $facebook->getUser($_GET['access_token']);

try {
$publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
'message' => 'test', 
'link'    => $FB_canvas_page,
'picture' => $submitPrefix. 'ibizasocial.com/plastik/images/logo_fb.png',
'name'    => 'Plastik',
'description'=> 'test'));


} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
//echo($e);
}


?>
<html>
<body style="810px; overflow:hidden">

<div style="overflow:hidden; width:810px;">
<img src="http://ibizasocial.com/dhapp/images/DHAPP3.jpg" border="0" />


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just a heads up: the message variable MUST be filled with user content only, see facebook rules.